# Check if a particular string occurs within another string in R

Tags: regex, r

I want to see whether or not a particular word occurs in a column.   It can be any capitalization and in the beginning or end or middle.   How do I go about doing this?  I tried looking at the regular expressions and grep() but I am getting stuck.

For example below I have a values column and a the indicated response that I desire.   I want to check for the word "dog".  I want a "1" if "dog" is found with any trailing stems such as "dogg" or "doggy", but I would NOT want a "1" if "dog" is preceeded by something else.

```
        mydf = structure(list(values = structure(c(7L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 9L,    8L, 
       5L, 6L), .Label = c("1 dog", "2 dog 3", "cats and dogs", "dog",  
      "DOG", "DOGG", "doggy", "no notthisdog", "not a valid value"), class =    "factor"), 
      result = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)), .Names = c("values", 
      "result"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

The regex `\b` matches a word boundary (start or end of a word, non-capturing), so `\bdog` (case insensitive, escaped) matches 'dog' at the start of a word. If you want more use-cases, you'll need to specify them.

```
mfdf$regex <- as.numeric(grepl("\\bdog", mydf$values, ignore.case=TRUE))
mydf
##              values result regex
## 1             doggy      1     1
## 2               dog      1     1
## 3             1 dog      1     1
## 4           2 dog 3      1     1
## 5     cats and dogs      1     1
## 6 not a valid value      0     0
## 7     no notthisdog      0     0
## 8               DOG      1     1
## 9              DOGG      1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
as.integer(grepl('\\bdog',mydf$values,ignore.case=T));
## [1] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
```

Or if you want the value itself:

```
grep(value=T,'\\bdog',mydf$values,ignore.case=T);
## [1] "doggy"         "dog"           "1 dog"         "2 dog 3"       "cats and dogs" "DOG"           "DOGG"
```